# iText html2pdf change size of the output PDF

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

How to change output PDF page size when converting it from HTML with `iText html2pdf` library?  Tried this code:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
MediaDeviceDescription description = MediaDeviceDescription.createDefault();
description.setHeight(1024);
description.setWidth(1024);
properties.setMediaDeviceDescription(description);
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(htmlSource), new File("outputFile.pdf"), properties);
```

but, looks like it does not work, my output page is still A4

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the `HtmlConverter`'s methods which take a `PdfDocument` instance as a parameter and set the needed page size on it with `setDefaultPageSize` method.

For example,

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destinationPath));
    pdfDoc.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(1500, 842));
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(sourcePath), pdfDoc);
```